# Is it possible to avoid sending repeated Slack notifications for already fired alert?

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, prometheus-alertmanager

Disclaimer: First time I use Prometheus.

I am trying to send a Slack notification every time a Job ends successfully.

To achieve this, I installed kube-state-metrics, Prometheus and AlertManager.

Then I created the following rule:

```
rules:
  - alert: KubeJobCompleted
    annotations:    
      identifier: '{{ $labels.instance }}'
      summary: Job Completed Successfully
      description: Job *{{ $labels.namespace }}/{{ $labels.job_name }}* is completed successfully.
    expr: |
      kube_job_spec_completions{job="kube-state-metrics"} - kube_job_status_succeeded{job="kube-state-metrics"}  == 0
    labels:
      severity: information
```

And added the AlertManager receiver text (template) :

```
{{ define "custom_slack_message" }}
{{ range .Alerts }}
    {{ .Annotations.description }}
{{ end }} 
{{ end }}
```

My current result: Everytime a new job completes successfully, I receive a Slack notification with the list of all Job that completed successfully.

I don't mind receiving the whole list at first but after that I would like to receive notifications that contain only the newly completed job(s) in the specified group interval.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using **kube_job_status_completion_time** and **time()** to dismiss past events (avoid refiring event upon repeat time).

```
rules:
  - alert: KubeJobCompleted
    annotations:    
      identifier: '{{ $labels.instance }}'
      summary: Job Completed Successfully
      description: Job *{{ $labels.namespace }}/{{ $labels.job_name }}* is completed successfully.
    expr: |
      time() - kube_job_status_completion_time < 60 and kube_job_spec_completions{job="kube-state-metrics"} - kube_job_status_succeeded{job="kube-state-metrics"}  == 0
    labels:
      severity: information
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add extra rule which will just display last completed job(s):

line: `for: <10m>` - which will list just lastly completed job(s) in 10 minutes:

```
rules:
  - alert: KubeJobCompleted
    annotations:    
      identifier: '{{ $labels.instance }}'
      summary: Job Completed Successfully
      description: Job *{{ $labels.namespace }}/{{ $labels.job_name }}* is completed successfully.
    expr: |
      kube_job_spec_completions{job="kube-state-metrics"} - kube_job_status_succeeded{job="kube-state-metrics"}  == 0
      for: 10m
    labels:
      severity: information
```